# kernel panic when install centos7

Tags: linux, centos

I'm trying to install centos7,but got a kernel panic:fatal exception. I have googled for a long time but I still can't fix this.Can anyone give me some suggestions?[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to review the way you've created the installer. If you used USB Key, due to the special partitioning which the CentOS7 installer image has, there are some problems possible if you've used some specific tools to create installer.

> the CentOS 7 installer image has a special partitioning which, as of
>   July 2014, most Windows tools do NOT transfer correctly leading to
>   undefined behaviour when booting from the USB key. Applications known
>   (so far) to NOT work are **unetbootin**, **multibootusb** and **"universal usb
>   installler"** - **do NOT use these**. Confirmed as functioning correctly are
>   Rufus (may depend on options selected, there have been reports of
>   failure with rufus too), Fedora LiveUSB Creator, Win32 Disk Imager,
>   Rawrite32 and dd for Windows.

See [wiki](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/InstallFromUSBkey) for more details.